# Spacing form elements with css

Tags: css

I am looking for a neat way to space my form elements but i am not so sure how to do it.

Currently,i am using the ordinary `<br/>` to space but i wonder if there was a better way of doing this using class or id

```
<form>
  Message: <input type="text" class="msg" name="message" /><br/><br/>
   <input type="submit" class="c-add" value="Add" />
   <input type="submit" class="c-update" value="Update" />
  </form>
```

I am thinking of

```
 .c-add + .c-update{
  margin-right:100px;
  }
```

but that's not valid css.What would be the solution?

Comment: What do you wanna do with that CSS?

Comment: That would be great but i am open to other solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.c-add + .c-update` is a valid CSS selector. It selects all elements with the "c-update" class that follow immediately an element with the "c-add" class. Example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4TYj/) ([CSS Selector Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp))

### Solution

You can seperate multiple selectors with a comma. You do not need to give each input a unique class name. That's only necessary if you want to style them uniquely. Since you did not provide information on how the expected result should look like, i made a demo with different solutions:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxwJu/)

HTML markup:

```
<form class="form">
   <label>Message:</label><input type="text" class="msg" name="message" />
   <input type="submit" class="add" value="Add" />
   <input type="submit" class="update" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Note that i wrapped "Message" with label, which is better markup.

CSS to make a one-row inline form:

```
.form input {
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}

.form label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

CSS to make a multiple-row form:

```
.form input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form label {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

​You can mix both approaches by using specific classes for each input element or type.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.I ended up using .crud-interface input.c-input{
  margin-right:100px;
  } as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/qrCyT/1/

Comment: i made an update (see the first paragraph) that explains that your initial selector is valid, but means something different

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma to separate selectors.

```
.c-add, .c-update {
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure, perhaps this way:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" />
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["name"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Email</span>
                <input type="text" name="email" />
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["email"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Subject</span>
                <input type="text" name="subject" />
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["subject"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>
                <span>Message</span>
                <textarea name="message" cols="80" rows="7"></textarea>
                <small class="errorText"><?php echo ($_POST["message"] == "") ? "This field is required" : ""; ?></small>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

And the CSS for the same:

```
* {font-family: Segoe UI, Tahoma;}
h1 {font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; padding: 5px 0; margin: 5px 0; border: 1px solid #999; border-width: 1px 0;}
input[type='submit'] {padding: 5px 20px; cursor: pointer;}
ul, li {display: block; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
ul li {padding: 5px 0;}
ul li label span {display: block; cursor: pointer;}
ul li label .errorText {color: #f00; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: top;}
ul li label textarea {width: 300px;}
```

You can see a live demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JHE22/)